# How exactly does this recursive code works?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, stack, iteration

I'm a Computer Science rookie, and recently entered University. I'm preparing this exam where i have to convert a recursive algorithm to an iterative form.

I find this pretty hard since, in this specific example i'm going to report, i totally don't understand what exactly this algorithm should do. Hence, i don't know how to convert it. Hope you can help me out.

[image: Pseudocode Screenshot]

In text format:

```vb
Algo(A, i, j)
    ret = i
    if (i <= j) then
        ret = Algo(A, i, ⌊(i+j)/2⌋)
        k = ret + 1
        while k <= j && A[k] <= A[ret] do
            k = k + 1
        if k % 2 = 1 then
            ret = Algo(A, k, j) + ret - k
        else 
            ret = Algo(A, k/2, k) + ret - k/2
    return ret
```

I know this could sound pretty stupid, but... i find this to be an infinite loop. Given that 'i' is the first index of our array, and 'j' the last, there would never be a case where the 'if i<=j' condition is false.
Given i=0, j=4, j would be 4, then 2, then 1. 1/2 is 0, and after that, 0/2 is 0. So i always equals j.
Maybe i'm just looking at it the wrong way.

I'm really struggling with this. Converting it to iterative is not really simple, even though my Professor gave me a scheme to follow, i don't find this easy at all.

FYI, this is the scheme he told me to follow:

```vb
while (!termination)
    if (new call) then
        ''simulate the beginning of a new call''
    else 
        ''retrieve context from stack''
        if (first call) then
            ... 
            ''execute second call''
        else
            ...
            ''end simulation''
```

Hope you can help me out. Just understanding how this program works, especially recursion-wise, would mean a lot to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pseudo code is wrong. Indeed, it would run into an infinite recursion. But `Algo(A,i,[(i+j)/2]` has several syntax issues... are you sure you got it right?

Comment: @trincot I added a screen of the code. Yeah, i forgot to close the final bracket. Take a look at the image for a more detailed look. Thank you for your time.

Comment: So indeed, I confirm, the algorithm is bad. Probably the `if` should have been `if i < j`, but we can only guess.

Comment: I thought the same thing. Anyway, let's say it should have been a 'if i<j'. Then, what does this program do? I can't figure out its... purpose. Well yeah, these kind of University things would never be written in a real program, it's just for the sake of understanding. Still, i don't understand. Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea what it calculates.

Comment: Wonderful. At least, i don't feel alone lol. Thank you for your time, and for editing my post. Appreciate that.

Comment: The algorithm suffering from infinite recursion has nothing to do with converting it to iterative; you are not asked to fix the algorithm or even understand it, only convert it. I will add, based on many poor quality tutorial questions I’ve seen posted here over the years, that it seems there are a great many “professors” sheltering in academia because they lack sufficient skill to work in a commercial setting.

Comment: That's what i understood now. I just have to convert it, and doing so by starting to understand what the program does, is not smart. I thought it would have helped me, but it only confused me more. And yes, i'm studying a whole lot of things that i totally don't see happening when writing code. Like, never.

Answer (score 0):

Divergence issues aside, the algorithm is equivalent to

```
return i
```

This can be proved by induction on the depth of the call stack. If the if condition is false, then the return value is `i`. Otherwise, we compute `ret = i` (as `Algo(A, i, floor((i+j)/2))`) and then increment by `Algo(A, x, j) - x = 0` for some `x`, also by induction.